# Async function not working as intended when called at onInit lifecycle hook

Tags: javascript, angular, observable

In my project I have a service that should load local database when the app is started. For that the function `GetData()` is used. I try to use it by calling at the `ngOnInit()` lifecycle hook. It logs the result in the console, but the property `datum` appears to be unchanged.

However, if I add `GetData()` method to a button, the property changes and data is displayed in the console as intended.

All sources that I looked through suggest that the right way to load the DB if I need it right away is to use `ngOnInit()` hook, that's why I don't wat to call `GetData()` when some event from the DOM is fired.

**Component**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  datum;
  constructor(private searchService: SearchService){ }
  getData(){
    this.searchService.getData().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.datum = data[0];
        console.log(this.datum);},
      err => console.log("E", err)
    );
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.getData();
  }
  title = 'app';
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{title}}!!
    Data: {{datum | json}}
  </h1>
  <button (click)="getData()">Click Me</button>
```

**App loaded**

[image]

**Button clicked**

[image]

**EDIT**
Implementation of `getData()` with `setTimeout()` as suggested by AlexKhymenko

```
  getData(){
    this.searchService.getData().subscribe(
      data => {
        setTimeout(() =>{
          this.datum = data[0];
        });
        console.log(this.datum);},
      err => console.log("E", err)
    );
  }
```

Comment: I would use a getter for such a situation: `get Datum() { return this.datum; };` and, in the view: `Data: {{Datum}}`. There may be several reasons for the data not to be displayed: either zone.js not firing, either something else. You may also try to use `Zone.run`, it should nevertheless be fixed with the getter already. Also, always initialize a class property, don't keep it undefined if it needs to theoretically be shown in the view. NgZone reference: https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone . alternatively, bind directly to getData in the dom, and return the observable, then add | async

Comment: I don't really get it. What is the purpose and impolementation of 'getter'? Is it just a function that returns `datum`? When should it be called?

Comment: @briosheje Maybe binding directly to `getData()` is the solution, since I used `datum` just because I don't fully grasp the concept of observables. How do I do it? Should it look something like {{ searchService.getData()? | async }}?

Comment: @briosheje tried using getter. Seems to be doing nothing. Did I do it right? I added `get Datum() {return this.datum;}` and bound to `Datum` not `datum` in the HTML

Comment: A getter should constantly update the view unless there is something wrong with `zone.js`. In this case, you need to run your code wrapped in a zone.run (check online). Else, you can use the `async` pipe by referencing an observable to it. It should work without async anyway, and should be working already, you should really check if there is something else wrong into your code elsewhere, either in the view, either somewhere else ;)

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is to run change Detection manually for example by calling setTimeout. I have created [a Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/8QPXqHl1zY2VhqPjQayr?p=preview).

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  datum;
  title = 'app';

  constructor(private searchService: SearchService){ }
       }

 ngOnInit(){
   this.getData();
 }
  getData(){
      this.searchService.getData().subscribe(
  data => {
   setTimeout(() => {
            this.datum = data[0];
   })
    console.log(this.datum);},
  err => console.log("E", err)
);

}
```

Comment: Either I'm doing something wrong or this is not helping. After implementint your suggestion the first result I get in the console is `undefined` and nothing is shown in the DOM. After clicking the button the result logget in the console is correct and information appears in the DOM

Comment: give me 5 minutes will create plunker

Comment: @IvanBespalov updated. It will load date after 2 seconds.

Comment: It will work even without setTimeout. But if it doesn't you can add setTimeout

Comment: I tried your approach. Begining to think my idea of using observables is damned in some way. I see that your example on plunker using promises works fine, but when I try  to add setTimeout to my code it does nothing, regardless of it it fires immediately or after 2sec delay

Comment: promise or observables it shouldn't matter. i implemented via promises cause its faster.

Comment: When you use timeout do you have response in data[0]?

Comment: Added my code with `setTimeout()` to the question, please, have a look.
With it I get identical results to what I had using my old approach

Comment: :-) not the right place add setTimeout where this.datum = data[]. Like i have done

Comment: I would say completely rewrite it. cause there are a lot of mistakes. dont put function in constructor.

Comment: Changed the place of setTimeout(), at first the result in the console is undefined, then, after clicking the button, correct.

Comment: Updated the plunker copy paste the code if it doesn't work the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: If I change my service to work with promises, like in your plunker, everything is fine and working as intended. I just can't help but feel like an idiot when working with observables. I don't get why if I use them here instead of promises it doesn't work correctly. And all the docs I find about them seem to not clarify anything, but make it more complicated. I wonder what's wrong

Comment: Try to use observable with 'first' operator.

Answer (score 0):

Because in subscribe function you get an observable object (not array).

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
   datum;
   constructor(private searchService: SearchService){ }
   getData(){
this.searchService.getData().subscribe(
  data => {
    //remove brackets
    this.datum = data;
    console.log(this.datum);},
  err => console.log("E", err)
 );
}

ngOnInit(){
   this.getData();
}
title = 'app';
}
```

Comment: Removing the brackets only change what I assign to `datum`. An array of objects as oppose to a single objects if I leave the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Try in HTML

```
<h1 *ngIf="datum !== null && datum !== undefined && datum !== ''">
Welcome to {{title}}!!
Data: {{datum | json}}
</h1>
```

Your datum variable was bind two-way data binding. When datum was not equal null or undefined or blank that time show that HTML tag.

Hope that help you.

Comment: Doesn't change much. At the startup nothing but the button is shown. Only when the button is clicked everything else appears.

Comment: Still the same behaviour, except, at the startup of the app only Click Me button is shown

Comment: Try to call this.getData(); method in constructor, because angular life cycle first constructor call.